# How long to dry wet clothes? Shuttleworth's evaporation formula in C# or Pseudocode

Tags: computer-science, approximation, mathematical-modeling

Please excuse my lack of knowledge when comes to mathematics formulas, hence me being here.

I'm writing a program that I'd like to calculate the approximate drying time for wet clothes to dry outside on a washing line.

Inputs:
* Air temperature / humidity
* Wind speed 
* Plus any others if required.

Output:
* Approximate time for clothes to dry

Ultimately the purpose of the program is to reduce the carbon print and usage of tumble dryers by encouraging people to dry washing outside.

I've come across Shuttleworth's formula for evaporation rate:

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penman_equation)

But am struggling with turning this into code.  I'm using C# but any type of pseudo-code would be hugely helpful.

Understand will be variables such as thickness of clothing and overall quantity of the washing load.  Even achieving an approximate time drying time within 10's of minutes would would feel like a great success.

Many thanks

Comment: Some neighbor associations do not allow out door drying.  I have even heard a homeowner state that he would not buy a home in a neighborhood if he saw clothes lines.  It gives kids too much knowledge.  My land lord complained about a few clothes I had drying on some bushes.

Answer (score 0):

Coding the actual computation should be trivial, a la

`E_mass := (m * Rn + rho_a * c_p * delta_e * g_a) / lambda_v / (m + gamma)`

However, where you get all those values from is a different question. Finally, it seems to be that this estimate is more adapted to landscapes, and of course there is a difference between evaporation from a lake the wind blows over and a piece of cloth hanging in and being shaken from the wind  (not to mention capillary forces etc.)